# console terminates instantly even with console.readline() at end

Tags: c#

```
      class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a number");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            int j = Int32.Parse(s);
            for (i = 0; i != j; i++) ;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

The code runs properly but when I press enter it terminates without executing the remaining code.

Comment: Try to remove ";" at the end of your for statement

Comment: when i enter a number and press enter it terminates aproven

Comment: Do you want the last `Console.ReadLine();` to be executed once or `j` times?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to happen. As noted in the answer posted below, the way your code is written the entire loop finishes execution before the following `Console.WriteLine(i);` statement executes. It's not clear whether this is what you want or not. What _is_ clear is that you would have to press the Return key _twice_ to get the program to exit; you seem to be saying you only need to press it once, i.e. immediately after typing a number.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
for (i = 0; i != j; i++) ;
```

You should remove the `;`, it prevents the following line from executing more than once.

Comment: Why it terminates after pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

If the given string input provided in `s` by the line `s = Console.ReadLine();` does not represent an integer value then the `Parse()` function throws a `FormatException` and it will be terminated.

If executed in Visual Studio then the debugger will break the execution and stops at this line. Maybe the `FormatException` is deactivated in your Visual Studio Exception Settings.

For a input string e.g. "`123`" the programm prints the number to the console and waits for a key press. I have validated this in my environment.